# Unable to capture Pyspark UDF exception

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am trying to parse a column containing date string using dateparser through PysparkUDF.

If the parsing fails would like to pass blank to the "date_field" column.

Though I am using "try-catch" to capture the Attribute error it is not working.
Even with except block ending up getting below error.
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'date'

```
import dateparser

        try:
            parse_date = udf(
                lambda z: dateparser.parse(z).date().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
                StringType(),
            )
            build_df = source_df.withColumn(
                "date_field",
                when(col(source_column_name).isNotNull(), to_date(parse_date(col(source_column_name)))).otherwise(" "),
            )
        except  AttributeError:
            build_df = source_df.withColumn("date_field", lit(" "))
        return build_df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. Spark uses lazy evaluation, so the function is not evaluated until you call something like `.show()`, `.collect()` or `.toPandas()`. Therefore the whole try block executes without error because Spark has not evaluated anything yet. It has only drawn up an execution plan.
2. To solve this problem, rather than catching the error, replace your lambda function with

```
lambda z: dateparser.parse(z).date().strftime("%Y-%m-%d") if z is not None else " "
```

and also replace the line

```
when(col(source_column_name).isNotNull(), to_date(parse_date(col(source_column_name)))).otherwise(" ")
```

with

```
to_date(parse_date(col(source_column_name)))
```

It's a known bug of Spark to evaluate the UDF even if the `when` condition is False, so put the condition inside the UDF instead.

Overall:

```
parse_date = udf(                
    lambda z: dateparser.parse(z).date().strftime("%Y-%m-%d") if z is not None else " ",
    StringType()
)

build_df = source_df.withColumn(
    "date_field",
     to_date(parse_date(col(source_column_name)))
)
```

Comment: Thanks for letting know the existing bug .Modified the udf to exclude column values when not able to parse - if dateparser.parse(z) is not None else " ".